# html5 audio addeventhandler

Tags: javascript, html

I made a html5 audioplayer with a limited loop function, but I can't manage to keep this functionality when I want to replace the audioplayer with buttons and adding an eventhandler to them. In this example the checkbox had to be checked and the 2nd option of the selectmenu must be selected, before the repeatfunction works. Somehow the repeat-function stops working when I add: 
"document.getElementById("Play").addEventListener("click", myFunction);". If I remove it, the code works, but only when I use the html audioplayer itself.
 My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 

<span style="font-family:arial; font-size:16px;"><b>Pre:</b></span>
<input id="precount" type="checkbox"><br><br>
<span style="font-family:arial; font-size:16px;"><b>Repeat:</b></span>
<select>
<option id="ok1">1x</option>
<option id="ok2">2x</option>
<option id="ok3">3x</option>
</select><br><br>

<audio id="myAudio" controls>
<source src="http://u1259p183.web0080.zxcs.nl/jQuery.mmenu-master/demo/sortablemenumobile/range_items/audio_notes/10_a.mp3">
</audio>

<script>
function PlaySound(soundobj) {
var thissound=document.getElementById(soundobj);
thissound.play();
}
function PauseSound(soundobj) {
var thissound=document.getElementById(soundobj);
thissound.pause();
}
</script>

<form>
<input type="button" value="PlaySound" id="Play">
<input type="button" value="PauseSound" id="Pause">
</form>


<script>

document.getElementById("Play").addEventListener("click", function);
var loopLimit = 2;
var loopCounter = 0;
var aud = document.getElementById("myAudio");
aud.onended = function() {
if ((loopCounter < loopLimit) &&    (document.getElementById("ok2").selected==true) &&(document.getElementById("precount").checked==true)){
this.currentTime = 0;
this.play();
loopCounter++;
}
};
</script>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Any syntax error in console ?

Comment: `.addEventListener("click", function);` that is a syntax error, you cannot use the keyword `function` there like that, unless you make a function definition, ie `function(){}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change line with event listener, and put variable definitions before it:

```
var aud = document.getElementById("myAudio");
var loopLimit = 2;
var loopCounter = 0;
document.getElementById("Play").addEventListener("click", function (){
    loopCounter = 0;
    aud.play();
});
```

Comment: Great! Do you also know how I can avoid the variable loses it's value after I used this script?

Comment: What variable? I can't see what is lost.

Comment: if I press the play-button it nicely repeats the audio twice, but when I do that again, it doesn't repeat anymore.

Comment: You must reset loopCounter variable, the easiest way to do that is changing order of variable initialization and event listener, I edited answer to show.

Comment: Sorry ban17, I have 1 additional question. I would like to make the loopLimit-value dependant on the value of the options in the selectmenu. So I replaced the line with the var LoopLimit = 2; with: var x = document.getElementById("mymenu").selectedIndex; var loopLimit = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value; it doesn't work however. Can you see what I did wrong?

Comment: Before line "if ((loopCounter < loopLimit) " add this:
var x = document.getElementById("mymenu");
    loopLimit = parseFloat(x.options[x.selectedIndex].value, 10);

Comment: Thanks so much. You made me happy.